# Symfony2: Using Sonata file field to upload a CSV file and store its content in a Doctrine json_array type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

In a Symfony project I need to store some table data on an entity, data which is supposed to be uploaded as a CSV document in Sonata admin. My first thought was to use the Doctrine2 `json_array` data type to store the data, but I was surprised to find out that it's not such a easy task.

After some research I found the [Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/DataTransformerInterface.html) which seemed to be the right choice to transform the CSV file into an array. The problem is that the `transform($value)` method is not receiving the uploaded file in `$value` parameter, so I'm stuck with this.

In the entity admin class I have:

```
$formMapper
    [...]
    ->add($formMapper->create('discounts', 'file', array(
        'required' => false,
        'data_class' => null
      ))
      ->addViewTransformer(new CSVToArrayTransformer()))
```

where `CSVToArrayTransformer` looks like this:

```
class CSVToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
   public function transform($csvFile){
       // here should take place the csv to array transformation, but $csvFile is null
   }
}
```

Is there a better method to obtain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by [Sonata documentation (Uploading and serving documents)](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_file_uploads.html), you should use the `prePersist` and `preUpdate` hooks to deal with the uploaded file after submitting the corresponding form.

Use something like this :

```
// Admin class

//...

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    $formMapper
        //...
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'required' => false,
            'data_class' => null,
        ))
        //...
    ;
}

// Called on submit create form.
public function prePersist($entity)
{
    $this->manageFileUpload($entity);

    return $entity;
}

// Called on submit edit form.
public function preUpdate($entity)
{
    $this->manageFileUpload($entity);

    return $entity;
}

protected function manageFileUpload($entity)
{
    $entity->convertUploadedCsvToArray($entity->getFile())        
}

//...
```

And in your entity :

```
// Entity

//...

// Unmapped property used for file upload
protected $file;

/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

/**
 * Get file.
 *
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * Upload attachment file
 */
public function convertUploadedCsvToArray()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    $this->getFile()->move('youruploadpath', $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());

    // Do your logic with the csv file here
    $transformer = new CsvDataTransformer();
    $discounts = $transformer->transform($this->getFile());

    // Set the field using result of parsing.
    $this->setDiscounts($discounts);

    // Empty the 
    $this->setFile(null);
}

//...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've read that cookbook receipe, but I don't think it helps. The `prePersist` and `preUpdate` methods are not able to change the `$entity` object received as a parameter. They can only use the data contained by it through `getSomething()` to perform additional tasks, but not `setSomething()`. In that recipe, you use the image data to save the image, which is a different entity. In my particular case I don't have an entity associated with the CSV file, I just need the data to save it with the same entity controlled by that admin class. I found the solution, will post it shortly. Thanks!

Comment: The example in doc use another entity, but prePersist can be used to set fields of the current entity. I have done the file upload by adding a non-mapped $file, calling my upload method and set the entity field with the uploadedFile informations, and all is done from the prePersist hook.

Comment: Well something must be different then. I tested this with another property and there was no change.

Comment: Something like this has no effect on `name` property: `public function prePersist($entity){$entity->setName($entity->getName() . ' CHANGED NAME IN PRE PERSIST');}`

Comment: You must add a `return $entity` at the end of prePersist method, and your fields will be set correctly. You can use it for timestamps or other fields that needs a custom default value recurrently or just to perform custom actions on create a new one.
Your solution is a perfect alternative, it doesn't involves changes in your admin class, also I upvote it. But take a look at mine, I've added changes in my answser, it's more precise and corresponding to your need.

Comment: My bad! You were right, your approach is better. I tested on `prePersist` while doing updates, that's why the data was not affected. My solution is not good at all actually or it needs more attention, because if I had no CSV file uploaded and submitted the admin form, the data got cleared in the database. Thank you! :)

Comment: After many edits and discuss with you, all the pleasure is for me ! :)